# Adding duplicate values in sql

Tags: sql

I'm just a newbie in programming and I'm having a problem with this (see table below).

```
    DocNum  DocDate   Quantity  ItemGroupCode   ItemGroupName
    89226   7-Nov-12    10     103            Fish-Fillet
    88768   8-Nov-12    1      104            Fish-Regular
    88856   6-Nov-12    2      104            Fish-Regular
    88678   20-Nov-12   12     109            Value Added
    89415   5-Nov-12    12     109            Value Added
    88642   5-Nov-12    1      112          Other Charges
    88646   5-Nov-12    20     112          Other Charges 
    88729   7-Nov-12    5.64   112          Other Charges 
    88804   12-Nov-12   10     112           Other Charges 
    88992   12-Nov-12   1      112             Other Charges
```

I want to combine similar Code of ItemGroupCode column then Add its Quantity. 
EX.

```
Quantity    ItemGroupCode   ItemGroupName
10              103          Fish-Fillet
3               104          Fish-Regular
24              109          Value Added 
38.64           112          Other Charges
```

Thanks ...
Pipay

Comment: What do you mean by "similar Code"? Is 103 similar to 104? What would be your expected result?

Comment: can you use any programming languages like java, php or need to do solely in sql?

Comment: I mean similar ItemGroupCode, expected results is in the 2nd table

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select sum(quantity) quantity, itemgroupcode, itemgroupname
from table_name
group by itemgroupcode, itemgroupname
```

For your question if I understand correctly, you need from the select you provide in your comments, to have the output of the first question. If this is the case then try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity), ItemGroupCode, ItemClass
FROM 
(SELECT A.DocNum, A.DocDate, B.Quantity,B.Price,B.Linetotal, A.Doctotal, C.ItemName, C.ItmsGrpCod as ItemGroupCode, 
       D.ItmsGrpnam as ItemClass 
FROM OINV as A LEFT outer JOIN INV1 As B ON A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM As C ON B.ItemCode = C.ItemCode 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN OITB As D ON C.ItmsGrpCod = D.ItmsGrpCod 
WHERE A.DocDate >= '11/01/2012' 
group by A.DocNum, A.DocDate, B.Quantity,B.Price,B.Linetotal, A.Doctotal, C.ItemName, C.ItmsGrpCod, D.ItmsGrpnam 
order by C.ItmsGrpCod ASC) X
GROUP BY X.ItemGroupCode, X.ItemClass
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, Ahmm.. This was my query to output the first table. (make it simplified since other columns are not that important with what I want). Kindly check?? cause I'm planning to make subqueries?

Comment: SELECT A.DocNum, A.DocDate, B.Quantity,B.Price,B.Linetotal, A.Doctotal, C.ItemName, C.ItmsGrpCod as ItemGroupCode, D.ItmsGrpnam as ItemClass
FROM OINV as A LEFT outer JOIN
 INV1 As B ON A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 OITM As C ON B.ItemCode = C.ItemCode LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 OITB As D ON C.ItmsGrpCod = D.ItmsGrpCod
WHERE A.DocDate >= '11/01/2012'
group by A.DocNum, A.DocDate, B.Quantity,B.Price,B.Linetotal, A.Doctotal, C.ItemName, C.ItmsGrpCod, D.ItmsGrpnam
order by C.ItmsGrpCod ASC

Comment: Yah, from that script I was able to display the first table above. then, from that script/table I want to display the second table.